# while loop stuck at same condtion

Tags: python, boto3

I have a code which creates a snapshot and then checks if it is done, i wrote the following code, but for some reason it doesn't update the `state` variable and the while loops keep printing the same thing even if the snapshot has been `completed`

The following is the code :

```
 def call_creater():
    regions = ['eu-central-1']
    for region in regions:
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region, aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, )
        snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId='vol-f9e7d220', Description='fra01-he-trial-ansible01')
        while snapshot.state != 'completed':
            print snapshot.state
            print "Snapshot under creation"
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            print "snapshot READY"
```

OUTPUT:

```
 pending
Snapshot under creation
pending
Snapshot under creation
pending
Snapshot under creation
pending
Snapshot under creation
```

This just keeps on printing the `"Snapshot under creation"` even though the snapshot gets completed. The reason for this is, i am not able to update my state `variable` i believe , please help me out how ?

Comment: Can you also print snapshot.state for each iteration. I would like to see if its value is "completed" or something else.

Comment: okay i am editing the code and printing the new output , please check

Comment: Too many print statements are confusing. Can you just print snapshot.state inside while loop but outside if-else. Also you can add break statement inside if condition.

Comment: okay , i am doing this now 

 `while snapshot.state != 'completed':
            print snapshot.state
            print "Snapshot under creation"
            time.sleep(10)
        else: 
            print "snapshot READY"`

Comment: @PratikGujarathi Check the new code and output

Answer (score 1):

```
snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId='vol-f9e7d220', Description='fra01-he-trial-ansible01')
```

This line is only executed once and at that instance the `state` is "`pending`". You have to recheck the state of `snapshot` variable again inside while loop.

You are not updating `snapshot` variable anywhere inside your code or `while` loop.

You will have to do something like this inside your while loop.

```
snapshot = conn.get_all_snapshots(snapshot_ids=[<YOUR SNAPSHOT ID>])[0]
```

Check the boto library and how to get the state of snapshot with id.

Comment: this is boto2 i suppose , what can i do for boto3

Answer (score 1):

As Pratik mentioned, your statement is only executing once and never updating. You can update your resource with `.load()`. Even better though, I recommend you use the [waiter](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.SnapshotCompleted). This will handle all the waiting logic for you and return when your snapshot is completed. For that resource, you would use: [`snapshot.wait_until_completed()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Snapshot.wait_until_completed).